# JBoss AS 7.1 not starting while Spring MVC web application is deployed

Tags: spring, jboss

1. I am new to JBoss AS. I am trying to deploy my web app from 'pivotal-tc-server' to 'JBOSS AS 7.1'

I have removed 'pivotal tc server', kept only JBoss AS 7.1

After running server following msg is shown in console...

15:07:29,488 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA

15:07:31,595 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA

15:07:31,841 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
..........................................
..........................................

then doesn't proceed anymore. Finally, server is not starting.

what is the exact cause.help me pls.

Comment: does server start when no app is deployed ?

Comment: NO. Following error is shown...

An internal error occurred during: "Starting JBoss 7.1 Runtime Server".
classToLaunch cannot be null

Comment: update the question with it, along with complete exception details

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond, I have replaced my server JBoss AS by wildfly.Then my web app is running. thnx ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just replaced my server JBoss AS by wildfly.Then my web app is running. thnx to all ...